# Difference between unary operators ( += , =+ , ++x , and x++)

Tags: c#, unary-operator

What is the difference between these unary operators in C#?

What would an example be? What is the name of each?

+= vs. =+

++x vs. x++

Comment: @remyabel: I'm pretty sure these operators will behave the same regardless of language.

Comment: `=+` is **not** an operator in C#. Take a look at `x =+ 2`. In this case what you are doing is assigning `x` to the positive value two. It's the same as `x = (+2)`. To be clear the `+` does nothing in this context because we are always assuming integers to be positive if not stated otherwise. Here is another example that will probably make more sense: `x =- 2` is actually the same as `x = (-2)` where you are assigning `x` to the negative value two.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They differ in how they change the value and how they return the result.

The first two `+=` and `=+` behave in the way that the first increments a variable, the other sets a variable. They are not related. Observe the following code:

```
// +=
x = 1;
printf( x += 1 ); // outputs 2, the same as x = x+1
printf( x );      // outputs 2

// =+
x = 1;
printf( x =+ 1 ); // outputs 1, the same as x = 1;
printf( x );      // outputs 1
```

The next two, `++x` and `x++`, differ in the order their function. `++x` will increment your variable by 1 and return the result. `x++` will return the result and increment by 1.

```
// ++x
x = 1;
printf( ++x ); // outputs 2, the same as x = x+1
printf( x );   // outputs 2

// x++
x = 1;
printf( x++ ); // outputs 1
printf( x );   // outputs 2
```

They are mostly useful for `for` loops and `while` loops.

In terms of speed, `++x` is considered a lot faster than `x++` since `x++` needs to create an internal temporary variable to store the value, increment the main variable, but return the temporary variable, basically more operations are used. I learned this a looong time ago, I don't know if it still applies

Comment: `=+` is **not** an operator in C#. Take a look at `x =+ 2`. In this case what you are doing is assigning `x` to the positive value two. It's the same as `x = (+2)`. To be clear the `+` does nothing in this context because we are always assuming integers to be positive if not stated otherwise. Here is another example that will probably make more sense: `x =- 2` is actually the same as `x = (-2)` where you are assigning `x` to the negative value two.

Answer (score 1):

Let's **visualize** the first ones, += and =+.

Because "+" is action, "=" is assignment, so

> += is to add BEFORE assignment
>
> =+ is a bit confusing with "+", it could be "-", for example a=+7 or a=-7, anyway, it's a direct assignment.

Similarly,

> ++x is "increment then return"
>
> x++ is "return then increase"

Comment: This is actually wrong. =+ simply assigns (the same as =) it turns out.

Comment: This was helpful to understand and remember this. Thanks.

Comment: @tobbenb3 This is actually because `=+` is not an operation. Take a look at `x =+ 2`. In this case what you are doing is assigning `x` to the positive value two. It's the same as `x = (+2)`. To be clear the `+` does nothing in this context because we are always assuming integers to be positive if not stated otherwise. Here is another example that will probably make more sense: `x =- 2` is actually the same as `x = (-2)` where you are assigning `x` to the negative value two.

Answer (score 1):

++x vs x++ are unary operators. ++x means pre increment and x++ means post increment.

```
int temp;
temp = 1;
Console.WriteLine(++temp); // Outputs 2
temp = 1;
Console.WriteLine(temp++); // outputs 1
Console.WriteLine(temp); // outputs 2
```

Prefix increment means:

> The result of the operation is the value of the operand after it has
>   been incremented.

Postfix increment means:

> The result of the operation is the value of the operand before it has
>   been incremented.

Now the following:
+= means temp +=  10; // same as temp = temp + 10;

This =+ isn't a valid operator. 
If one does this:

```
str = + str;  // will throw an error.
int a;
a = +2; // sort of meaningless . 2 and +2 means same.
```

More here: [Is there such thing as a "=+" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184535/is-there-such-thing-as-a-operator/31184658)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator