# Is there such thing as a "=+" operator?

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I'm wondering why is `+=` valid but `=+` is not valid. Let's say I have code like this:

```
string strOne = "World!";
strOne =+ "Hello ";//strOne = "Hello " + strOne; not valid
//Error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'
//Intended Output: Hello World!

string strTwo = "Hello ";
strTwo += "World!";//strTwo = strTwo + "World!"; valid
//Output: Hello World!
```

I'm also not sure whether `strOne =+ "Hello ";` is same as `strOne = "Hello " + strOne;`. Are there any rules on why `=+` is not valid or cannot be syntactically correct?

Comment: What language is this? Add the relevant language tag...

Comment: The language I used was C#. :)

Comment: No, there is no such syntax. Only `+=`. As someone just commented, you may be confusing the situation in that `int x=+3` is actually two operators, just squashed together with poor formatting.

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason there is no /= and *=

Comment: Its confusing and irrelevant to have multiple operators doing the same thing. It was never defied be it C, C++ or C#. So be sure it never existed.

Comment: You may be able to define "=+" yourself.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth use of the word trolling can be quite daring ;-) Although I have to admit that this question bugged me a bit, like every answer that can easily be answered by using a search engine or language reference. I see that SO is more and more used as a crowdsourcing search engine ;-)

Comment: Yes, there is such operator, but it sets a variable instead of increment. Don't know about string type, but for integer it works well. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358432/5113030. (In case it's C# or such language...)

Comment: This is in fact a very valid question. I don't get why you have been down voted.

`=+` is **not** an operator in C#. Take a look at `x =+ 2`. In this case what you are doing is assigning `x` to the positive value two. It's the same as `x = (+2)`. To be clear the `+` does nothing in this context because we are always assuming integers to be positive if not stated otherwise. Here is another example that will probably make more sense: `x =- 2` is actually the same as `x = (-2)` where you are assigning `x` to the negative value two.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is no, there is not a `=+` operator. You would have to do

```
strTwo = "Hello " + strTwo;
```

Part of the reason that there isn't could be that `+` is a valid unary operator for number types.

```
var intValue = +2;
```

Answer (score 3):

It nothing to do with rules or syntactical correctess in principle, but it concerns the fact that that operator does not exist in the C# language.

Anyway, I would suggest never using + or += operators with strings. It's a bad habit that can chew up memory if strewn throughout an application.

Use `string.Concat` or `string.Format` instead, for example. Or StringBuilder for large string operations.