# Is there a difference between x => x + 1 and x => x += 1?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm currently learning functional programming, and I was wondering if there is a difference between these functions.

```
Func<int, int> incrementByOne = x => x += 1;
Func<int, int> incrementByOne2 = x => x + 1;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of Unary operators ( += , =+ , ++x , x++ )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358241/difference-of-unary-operators-x-x)

Comment: Have you tried them out?

Comment: This has no thing to do with functional programming

Comment: @Fildor, Yes, I have. And that's why I am posting here to understand why there is no difference. Which works faster and so on.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ , it does have a functional programming aspect, because functional programming means avoiding side effects, but here a `+=` operator is used, and to infer that it produces no side effects, one need to know about value types

Comment: Change  it to `Func<ref int, int>` and then it would make a diiference.

Comment: @ilkerkaran - that is not the point of this question. Not a dupe candiate at all.

Comment: Adding two integers is extremely fast, no matter which variant of the two shown here you are using (i wouldn't use the 1st one though, because it is a weird code construct that can potentially cause confusion and misinterpretation when reading code). The performance cost of invoking this addition through the delegates is vastly more expensive in comparison, making any possible (or not) tiniest performance differences between using `x+=1` and `x+1` completely irrelevant...

Comment: There is a huge difference, the first version is behind the [door on the right](https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. Because:

1. `int` is a value type, so passed by value (being copied), thus in `x => x += 1` changing `x` cannot affect the source (no side effects)
2. `+=` returns the result of addition, so the same as `+` does

Comment: Well, no difference in result, that is. I could also imagine, it gets optimized to the same IL code. But syntactically it is not the same, obviously.

Comment: 'Syntactically'  is not the main criterion. It is often possible to write something in different ways.