# Value cant go higher than one in unity

Tags: c#

So i have 2 coins, if one of them is destroyed, add one to "count"
i expected so that if both coins are destroyed, "count" value would increase by two, but no, value still remains as one, (as if like only one of these coins would be destroyed).

I want it to be 2, because 1+1 is 2,
i have no clue why this doesnt work..
If you would help me solve this problem i would appreciate that.

```
void Update()
{
private float count = 0;
if(coin == null)
        {
            count =+1;
        }
        else if (coin2 == null)
        {
            count =+1;
        }
        if(count == 2)
        {
            Destroy(door);
        }
}
```

as i said in previous introduction.

i need "count" to have value of 2, but it just stops at one.

As a beginner, i tried lots of things but not a single one of them worked.

Comment: You're probably executing `private float count = 0` each time that you're taking input. So you're always setting it back to 0.

Comment: That code permits only one coin to be destroyed.  Delete `else`.

Comment: `private float count = 0` within a method doesn't compile. Playing guessing games between what your showing and what you're actually attempting to compile is no fun for anyone. Please produce a [mcve]

Comment: `count =+1;` -> `count += 1;`

Comment: I tried all of these, none worked sadly, if i replace "else if" with simply "if", it doesnt work. If i swap =+ with += it also doesnt work, it increases "count" value by hundreds a second.

Comment: There is no operator `=+`. When you have `count =+1`, you are assigning the value `+1` to `count`. I don't see how `count += 1` would only increment `count` by `0.01`???  And why are you declaring a local variable `private`?? Also if you are dealing with integer values use an `int`, not `float`.  Anyway, the whole function can be written as `if (coin == null && coin2 == null) Destroy(door);`

Comment: So answer was really simple! This crazy man saved my headache... Thanks, 001

Answer (score 3):

If both coins are destroyed (their value is null), then else if will not trigger because the first condition will pass. You should try removing 'else' statement. Additionally, the operator you've assigned is not correct. Please check the unary operators and the differences between them here [Difference between unary operators ( += , =+ , ++x , and x++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358241/difference-between-unary-operators-x-and-x) At the end your method would look like this:

```
private float count = 0;
if(coin == null)
{
   count += 1;
}
if (coin2 == null)
{
   count += 1;
}
if(count == 2)
{
   Destroy(door);
}
```

Additionally, it is worth mentioning what one user posted in comment - you do not need a counter, everything can be resolved in one if statement with 2 conditions if you apply logical operators [C# - Logical Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_logical_operators.htm)

```
if(coin==null && coin2==null) Destroy(door);
```

Comment: Which still will never trigger `Destroy(door)`.

Comment: @Fildor You are right, I didn't realize that '=+' is not a valid operator. Thought it's like the situation with i++ vs ++i